# mysql group by php concat

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table of fixtures in my DB: hometeam, awayteam, date, time

I am currently using `mysql_fetch_array` and getting the following:

```
hometeam    awayteam    date         time
--------------------------------------------
Blackburn   Wolves      13/08/2011   3:00pm
Arsenal     Liverpool   13/08/2011   3:00pm
etc
```

I want to return:

```
13/08/2011
---------------------------
Blackburn, Wolves, 3:00pm
Arsenal, Liverpool, 3:00pm
etc
```

I have tried group by date, but this just returns 1 fixture for that date which is rubbish.

I have also tried `group_concat`, but the problem with this is I need to modify the items in this group, such as changing the time format from server time to a readable time like above.

Comment: You want the date as the column name?

Comment: yeah as it relates to each fixture :)

Comment: Lemme guess - this needs to be dynamic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can sort by date and then check in php when the date changes between two rows. something like this:

```
function h($s) { return htmlspecialchars($s); }
$conn = mysqli_connect(…);
$result = mysqli_query($conn, 'select * from fixtures order by date');

$lastdate = NULL;
while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) !== FALSE) {
  if($lastdate != $row['date']) {
    // output date divider/header
    echo '<h1>',h($row['date']),'</h1>';
    $lastdate = $row['date'];
  }

  echo h($row['hometeam']), ', ', h($row['awayteam']), ', ', h($row['time']);
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, this just seems to be a very heavy way to do something i thought would be a lot simpler :(

Comment: it's not heavy at all, the only expensive operation is `order by`. all records are only iterated over once and you use one additional variable. and sorting has to happen at some point (i guess you want to output your fixtures ordered by date anyway …)

Comment: thanks again for your time on this, I am getting an error with this code, and it takes ages to load

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\football\test.php on line 4

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\wamp\www\football\test.php on line 7

any ideas?