# Group PHP results on first letter of name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query which gets all records ordered by last_name. Now I would like to create a loop that groups these results by the first letter of the last name and display the letter above the group i.e.

```
A
-----------
Albert
Alfred

C
-----------
Charles

D
-----------
Delta etc...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Order the results by `lastname` on `MySQL` side and track the change of the first letter on `PHP` side:

```
<?php

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY lastname");

while ($rec = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    if ($initial !== strtoupper(substr($rec['lastname'], 0, 1)) {
        $initial = strtoupper(substr($rec['lastname'], 0, 1));
        print "$initial\n";
    }
    print $rec['lastname'] . "\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: This one worked...after changing $initial !== strtoupper(substr($rec['lastname'], 1, 1) to $initial !== strtoupper(substr($rec['lastname'], 0, 1)

Answer (score 4):

```
$letter = null;
foreach ($array as $word) {
  if ($letter != $word[0]) {
    $letter = $word[0];
    echo '<b>'.strtoupper($word[0]) . '</b><br/>';
  }
  echo strtoupper($word) . '<br/>';
}
```

and to tour query add line :

```
order by `your_field` asc
```

Comment: same problem and solution as in [mysql group by php concat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719061/mysql-group-by-php-concat/6719354#6719354)

Answer (score 3):

Allready tried something like this?

```
$last = '';
foreach($data as $key=>$row){
    if(substr($row['last_name'],0,1)!=$last) echo '<br /><br />'.substr($row['last_name'],0,1).'<br />----------------<br />';
    $last = substr($row['last_name'],0,1);
    echo $row['last_name'];
}
```

Comment: Wow impressive! I am writing much too slow! :D

Answer (score 2):

In your view you could then loop the records and split them up:

```
$current = '';
foreach ($rows as $r) {
    if (!$current || strtolower($r['name'][0]) != $current) {
        $current = strtolower($r['name'][0]);
        echo strtoupper($current).'<br />---------------';
    }
    echo $row['name'].'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your query, try adding something like:

```
group by substr(last_name,1,1)
```

i.e.

```
select substr(last_name,1,1) as alpha, *
from tableName
group by substr(last_name,1,1)
```

Comment: This will only return a single record for each initial letter

Comment: Quassnoi is right. Use `ORDER BY LEFT(last_name,1) ASC` instead. Btw.. As long you want to query all rows you won't be able to retrieve such 'blocked' results. In the end you will have to do the final 'blocking' in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achive this using `MySql` itself

In my case brand_name going to be list out as you expected.

Example :

```
SELECT id, upper(SUBSTR(brand_name, 1, 1))  AS alpha FROM products WHERE  brand_name != ''  group by alpha
UNION
SELECT id, upper(SUBSTR(brand_name, 1, 1))  AS alpha FROM products WHERE  brand_name != '' order by brand_name COLLATE NOCASE
```

Result :

```
    A
    A Card
    A Cef
    A Cef O
    B
    Bacticef Tab
    Bacticin
    Bactidrox
    Bactidrox Kid
    ........
```

Hope it will help someone.