# Group records in CakePHP based on first letter?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I'm wanting to fetch and group records from a database table by the first letter. So for example:

> **A**
>   Alfred
>
> **B**
>   Brian
>
> **C**
>   Christopher
>
> ...

Ideally, I'd like my data structure to come out as follows:

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [Person] => Array
            (
                [id] => 12
                [name] => Alfred
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I could do this with a raw MySQL query, but not sure if CakePHP supports this out of the box. I'm just literally wanting records grouped so I can iterate over them and create an unordered list for each letter:

```
<h2>A</h2>
<ul>
  <li>Alfred</li>
</ul>
<h2>B</h2>
<ul>
  <li>Brian</li>
</ul>
<h2>C</h2>
<ul>
  <li>Christopher</li>
</ul>
...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group PHP results on first letter of name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760222/group-php-results-on-first-letter-of-name)

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is: order them by name and then sort them in a loop:

```
$people = $this->Person->find('all', array(
    'order' => 'Person.name ASC'
));
```

And then you could do:

```
$letter = '';
foreach($people as $person) {
    $firstLetter = strtolower(substr($person['Person']['name'], 0, 1));
    if ($firstLetter !== $letter) {
        $letter = $firstLetter;
    }
    $_people[$letter][] = $person;
}
$people = $_people;
```

Or just do it directly in the view so you don't need to loop it twice:

```
<ul>
<?php $letter = 'first'; ?>
<?php foreach ($people as $person) : ?>
    <?php $firstLetter = strtolower(substr($person['Person']['name'], 0, 1)); ?>
    <?php if ($firstLetter !== $letter) : ?>
        <?php if ($letter !== 'first') : ?>
            </ul></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $letter = $firstLetter; ?>
        <li><h2><?php echo $firstLetter; ?></h2><ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <li><?php echo $person['Person']['name']; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul></li></ul>
```

I wouldn't know how to get this structure just by using a find call (except for making 26 calls or creating a db table containing all letters) and I don't see why that would be neccesairy.

Hope that helps! (ps code isn't tested... but you get the point. should there be any typos)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$peoplebyletter = array();

foreach($people as $person){
    $peoplebyletter[strtolower(substr($person['Person']['name'], 0, 1))][] = $person;
}

debug($peoplebyletter);
```

Not tested. Let me know if it works.