# PHP MySQl : Alphabetical Ordered list with Heading and anchored link with aplabets

Tags: php, mysql, alphabetical, listings

I was trying on Alphabetical ordered list with Alphabets heading linked to list of alphabets at the top of the table.

For Instance:
A - C - D - F - G ............

```
A
Alabama
Alaska

California
Colorado
Connecticut

D
Delaware

F
Florida

etc.
```

as you see Letters "B" and "E" missing as they do not exist in table.

Any help will be deeply appreciated and will also help others too.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Post your tried effort & code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760222/group-php-results-on-first-letter-of-name

Comment: Are you trying to order it using mysql? or php?

Comment: this might be a fun use of substring and group_concat :)

Comment: @JmVerastigue bit different question here i think OP wants the missing letters to show

Comment: @Orangepill i think ops question is to show missing letters as op loop

Comment: Tried to list has some error and need alphabets with row of letters with anchor tag

<code>
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newjersey_new ORDER BY city ASC") or die('Data Retrival Error : ' . mysql_error());
$next = '';

while ($pst = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $cloc = strtolower($pst['city'][0]);
    if ($next != $cloc) {
        echo '<a href="#' . $cloc .'">' . strtoupper($cloc) . "</a><br />";
        $next = $cloc;
    }
 
 $pcity = str_replace(' ','_',strtolower($city));
    echo '<a href="doctors_' . $pcity .'_nj.php">'.$pst['city'].'</a><br />';
}
</code>

Thanks

Comment: sorry for mess of codes as am new to stack...

Comment: You can edit your post to include the code. It will be more readable there.

Answer (score 0):

```
select substring(stateName, 1, 1) as state_init, group_concat(stateName, ",") from usStates group by state_init;
```

Might give you a good starting point

Comment: Orangepill you are a MasterDB.  Thanks Bro that was great help. Fantastic and thanks all of you. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a conceptual answer with some technical aspects. you build an array of the Alphabet and then you iterate through the array while querying the database for each alphabetical result.

```
$alpha = str_split("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");

foreach ($alpha as $letter) {
        echo $letter;
        //db-query("WHERE item REGEXP '^{$letter}'");
        //loop through results
}
```