# How to using distinct in correct way

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, distinct

i want to create page to index all title that i have.

i want to print firstword for each title.

for example i have title like this

1. atitle1
2. atitle2
3. btitle3
4. vtitle4

so, i want to create index like this

```
A
atitle1
atitle2

B
btitle3

V
vtitle4
```

here what i try

```
SELECT * FROM master_post, 
      category_relation, 
      category WHERE category_relation.id_mp = master_post.id_mp 
      AND category_relation.id_c = category.id_c
      AND category.slug_c = 'dorama' AND 1 ORDER BY master_post.judul_mp ASC
```

im not sure but i think it using `Distinct`. here `Distinct` that i create

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(judul_mp, 1) AS firstletter FROM master_post WHERE judul_mp = :judul_mp
```

but i dont know how to join my `distinct` code, i try it but error.

Comment: You should handle such display related things in your application code.

Comment: no, well, i dont think thats what `DISTINCT` for. Madhur idea is the easiest one as there already [preceeding question with answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6760333/4648586).

Comment: Your first query returns many columns.  Your second returns one column.   Your sample results have one column.  I'm confused on what you really want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
SELECT mp.judul_mp as str
FROM master_post mp JOIN 
     category_relation cr
     ON mp.id_mp = cr.id_mp JOIN
     category c
     ON cr.id_c = categcry.id_c
WHERE c.slug_c = 'dorama'
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(mp.judul_mp, 1)
FROM master_post mp JOIN 
     category_relation cr
     ON mp.id_mp = cr.id_mp JOIN
     category c
     ON cr.id_c = categcry.id_c
WHERE c.slug_c = 'dorama'
ORDER BY str;
```

Note the use of proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  Do not use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: but how if i want to add one more `AND`? I want to add `WHERE mp.judul_mp = :charac`

Comment: @Jazuly . . . You would add it to both `where` clauses.

Comment: how if i want to select multiple column, i try add `SELECT mp.judul_mp as str, mp.link_mp as lnkstr` not working

Comment: cause this is index i want to add link, and i insert link in my `master_post` table called `link_mp`

Comment: @Jazuly . .  That would be a different question and should be asked as a *new* question.

Comment: @Jazuly . . . Do not edit an already answered question!  That is rude to anyone who has tried to help, because it can invalidate answers, which draws downvotes.  Ask a new question.